# Issue with array.length and setInterval()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background information: I'm retrieving an XML file every minute, parsing it, and appending the contents to an html table.

Here's the setInterval function

```
setInterval(function(){
  data.length = 0;
  deleteRows();
  ajaxGet('rest/room/wakeup/?type=pending', parsePending);
  appendAll();
  console.log("refreshed");
}, 60000);
```

Data is an array of arrays. Each sub array contains a row of the table I'd like to append. Data is declared globally.

ajaxGet retrieves the XML file and calls the parsing function to process and pushes each row array into the data array. The parsing function logs each row to the console so I know it's working correctly.

Now here's where things go wrong.

```
function appendAll(){
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var row = "<tr>";
    console.log("row appended");
    for (var key in data[i]){
       row = row + "<td>" + data[i][key] + "</td>";
       console.log("appended" + data[i][key]);
    }
    row = row + "</tr>";
    $("#pending_wakeups tbody").append(row);
  }
  console.log("appended");
}
```

If any function within setInterval clears data before appendAll(), data.length will return 0. Despite the parsing function returning a full array to the console one call before appendAll(), it refuses to work for me.

Comment: Is `ajaxGet` asynchronous? Then you should call `appendAll` in the callback.

Comment: Yes it is asynchronous. I'll give that a shot

Comment: Trying to use a global variable that's set in an ajax callback before the callback completes is a recipe for failure.

Comment: @Oriol That worked! Thank you so much! ah I'm an idiot